# R : multidimensional scaling

Tags: r, multi-dimensional-scaling

I have several questions:
1. What's the difference between isoMDS and cmdscale?
2. May I use asymmetric matrix?
3. Is there any way to determine optimal number of dimensions (in result)?

Comment: You might want to consider breaking these up into 2-3 different questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. One of the MDS methods is `distance scaling` and it is divided in metric and non-metric. Another one is the `classical scaling` (also called `distance geometry` by those in bioinformatics). Classical scaling can be carried out in R by using the command `cmdscale`. Kruskal's method of nonmetric distance scaling (using the stress function and isotonic regression) can be carried out by using the command `isoMDS` in library MASS. 
   The standard treatment of `classical scaling` yields an eigendecomposition problem and as such is the same as PCA if the goal is dimensionality reduction. The `distance scaling` methods, on the other hand, use iterative procedures to arrive at a solution.
2. If you refer to the distance structure, I guess you should pass a structure of the class `dist` which is an object with distance information. Or a (symmetric) matrix of distances, or an object which can be coerced to such a matrix using as.matrix(). (As I read in the help, only the lower triangle of the matrix is used, the rest is ignored).
3. (for classical scaling method): One way of determining the dimensionality of the resulting configuration is to look at the eigenvalues of the `doubly centered` symmetric matrix B (= HAH). The usual strategy is to plot the ordered eigenvalues (or some function of them) against dimension and then identify a dimension at which the  eigenvalues become “stable” (i.e., do not change perceptively). At that dimension, we may observe an “elbow” that shows where stability occurs (for points of a n-dimensional space, stability in the plot should occur at dimension n+1). For easier graphical interpretation of a classical scaling solution, we usually choose n to be small, of the order 2 or 3.